# Joomla JHTML Grouped buttons

Tags: list, joomla3.0

Im trying to bild a joomla component where the user can choose two options (for example yes/no). 
Joomla has the possibility to add grouped buttons through an XML file with radio & class "btn-group btn-group-yes-no". However it is also possible to add a form list through JHTML: JHTML::_('select.genericList', $publish, 'published', ' class="inputbox" '. '', 'value', 'text', published)

I can't find it anywhere on the internet, so i think its impossible through JHTML. I want to add a btn-group through JHTML...

Thanks for your effort!

Ron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying do it for Joomla! 3.x you should just write at the XML file like this:

```
`<field name="enable_quantity" type="radio" class="btn-group" default="0"
 label="Enable quantity"
>
 <option value="0">JNO</option>
 <option value="1">JYES</option>
</field>`
```

It's valid with using JForm editing model.